# Plotting the roots of a polynomial in 3D in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

do you know a neat way to plot the roots of a polynomial f(x,y,z) in 3D?

In Mathematica this is possible via the function [ContourPlot3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html).

In matplotlib I do not see how one can cope with the problem of several possible solutions (where different surfaces might intersect each other).

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: why 3D? f(x,y)=0 is a subset of a plane

Comment: yea, sorry Andres, I corrected it

Comment: no problem! I'm not experienced with matplotlib, but [SageMath](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/prep/Advanced-2DPlotting.html#contour) makes this excessively easy and is built on top of python. You can simply do ```f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1\\
implicit_plot3d(f(x,y,z)==0, (x,-pi,pi), (y,-pi,pi),(z,-pi,pi), viewer='threejs')``` inside of a jupyter notebook

Comment: You are right Andres. I looked into the sourcecode of SageMath; it seems it all boils down to the following routine https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/9db4320e485ed0aeae56d2c9dfc91fabe14659b1/src/sage/plot/plot3d/implicit_surface.pyx which is far from trivial!